# Why are parameters to Bash's `command` and `type` optional?

Tags: bash

Similar to [Why are parameters to Bash's builtin optional?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36751/why-are-parameters-to-bashs-builtin-optional), these commands print nothing and return exit code 0 if no parameters are provided. But unlike `builtin`, their `help` output state that *at least one parameter is mandatory*. Is this a bug, a feature, or did I misunderstand something?

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ type -a command
command is a shell builtin
$ type -a type
type is a shell builtin
$ help -s command
command: command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
$ help -s type
type: type [-afptP] name [name ...]
$ command
$ echo $?
0
$ type
$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX thinks the command parameter is required.  So it could be a bug.

[POSIX 2008 command specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html)

Comment: Looks like the [`type` synopsis](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html#tag_20_136_02) says the same - Optional parameters would be in brackets.

Answer (score 2):

For `command`, the immediate explanation is probably that ksh does the same thing (at least ATT ksh93, pdksh and mksh do nothing when you run `command` with no argument, I don't have ATT ksh88 to test).

Why ksh behaves that way, I don't know. A tentative explanation is that `command foo` is a lot like `foo`, and if you leave out `foo`, you get a shell command that does nothing (but still performs redirections). Strangely, with ksh 93s+ 2008-01-31 (but not with pdksh, mksh, bash, ash or zsh), `ksh -c 'foo=bar command; echo $foo'` displays `bar`, which means that the assignment is treated as a shell variable assignment and not as a command-local environment assignment. This behavior is expected only of [special built-in utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_14), which [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/command.html) is not (the rationale explains why not). This looks like a bug in ksh93.

In ksh, `builtin` displays a list of built-in utilities, which is useful.

`type` is a different case: it accepts multiple arguments, and reports on each in turn (e.g. `type ls cd`). Having zero arguments is a natural continuation of this behavior.